# How to prevent memory leaks in code that uses std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17

Recently I've been working on a scheme interpreter in c++.  For version 2, I've rewritten it so it uses a linked list of cons cells internally.  So far so good.  Now I'm implementing append which should take two lists and concatenate them into two one list.  The code shown below works.  It outputs:

```
(1,2)
(3,4)
(1,2,3,4)
```

as it should.  However valgrind reveals that it is leaking memory. (definitely lost: 80 bytes in 2 blocks indirectly lost: 240 bytes in 8 blocks)  I think this is because of all the objects I'm creating in main()  Their pointers are being copied into Cons's constructor and the copy never gets deleted.  Is this right?

So I should pass them by reference or move them somehow right?  Unfortunately my attempts to do so led to many more errors.  Can anyone show me how to make this code leak-free?

```
typedef enum { CONS = 0, ATOM = 1, FUNCTION = 2, LAMBDA = 3 } Type;

class Expression {
public:
    explicit Expression(Type type) : type_{type} {
    }

    virtual ~Expression() {}

    Type type_;
};

class Cons : public Expression {
public:
    Cons(Expression* car = nullptr, Expression* cdr = nullptr) :
    Expression(Type::CONS), car_{car}, cdr_{cdr} {
    }

    ~Cons() {
        if (car_) {
            delete car_;
        }
    }

    Expression* car_;
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> cdr_;
};

class Atom : public Expression {
public:
    Atom(const char* value) : Expression(Type::ATOM), value_{value} {
    }

    Atom(std::string value) : Atom(value.c_str()) {
    }

    std::string value_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Expression* exp) {
    switch(exp->type_) {
        case Type::ATOM:
            out << dynamic_cast<Atom*>(exp)->value_;
            break;
        case Type::CONS: {
            out << "(";
            auto current = dynamic_cast<Cons*>(exp);
            while (current) {
                out << current->car_;
                if (current->cdr_) {
                    out << ' ';
                }
                current = dynamic_cast<Cons*>(current->cdr_.get());
            }
            out << ")";
            break;
        }
        case Type::FUNCTION:
        case Type::LAMBDA:
            break;
    }

    return out;
}

void traverse(Expression* exp, std::function<void(Expression*)> process) {
    if (exp) {
        if (exp->type_ == Type::CONS) {
            auto cell = dynamic_cast<Cons*>(exp);
            traverse(cell->car_, process);
            traverse(cell->cdr_.get(), process);
        } else {
            process(exp);
        }
    }
}

Expression* append(Expression* first, Expression* second) {
    Cons* ret = nullptr;
    auto add_to_ret = [&ret](Expression* cell) -> void {
        if (ret == nullptr) {
            ret = dynamic_cast<Cons*>(new Cons(cell));
        } else {
            auto temp = ret;
            while(temp->cdr_) {
                temp = dynamic_cast<Cons*>(temp->cdr_.get());
            }
            temp->cdr_.reset(new Cons(cell));
        }
    };

    traverse(first, add_to_ret);
    traverse(second, add_to_ret);

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    Expression* list1 = new Cons(
            new Atom("1"),
            new Cons(
                new Atom("2"),
                nullptr
            )
        );
    std::cerr << list1 << '\n';

    Expression* list2 = new Cons(
            new Atom("3"),
            new Cons(
                new Atom("4"),
                nullptr
            )
        );
    std::cerr << list2 << '\n';

    Expression* joined = new Cons(
        list1,
        nullptr
    );

    joined = append(joined, list2);

    std::cout << joined << '\n';

    if (joined) {
        delete joined;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Note that Scheme will most probably create circular references and reference counting (implemented by shared pointer) can not cope with that.

Comment: Yikes.  Well dealing with that will be in the next version. :-)

Comment: I think that sanitizers will give you better error message, specifying where memory was leaked from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to prevent memory leaks in code that uses std::shared_ptr

Avoid raw `new` and `delete`. Always use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` when you need an owning pointer. Use raw pointers only as non-owning handles. Use `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` to create objects that are owned by smart pointers. Don't call `.release()` on `unique_ptr`s. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Yes ok but _how_ is the question.  My Cons class has a std::shared_ptr member which I'm trying to initialize.  Are you suggesting I wrap the new's in std::make_shared?  Because I tried that and got more problems.  A concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: Don't wrap the `new` - *replace* it with `std::make_shared`. [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) has an example on how to use `make_shared`. Then, pass `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` instead of the raw pointers. You can avoid calling `reset` - just assign a new smart pointer, when the old one is no longer referenced cleanup happens automatically

Comment: @Jaldhar Rewrite your `Cons` class so that it doesn't have an owning raw pointer `car_`. Rewrite the constructor so that it doesn't take owning raw pointers as arguments.

Comment: Thanks to all; I've got it now.